# Haskell: Concurrent data structure guidelines

Tags: performance, haskell, concurrency, ioref

I've been trying to get a understanding of concurrency, and I've been trying to work out what's better, one big `IORef` lock or many `TVar`s. I've came to the following guidelines, comments will be appreciated, regarding whether these are roughly right or whether I've missed the point.

---

Lets assume our concurrent data structure is a map `m`, accessed like `m[i]`. Lets also say we have two functions, `f_easy` and `f_hard`. The `f_easy` is quick, `f_hard` takes a long time. We'll assume the arguments to `f_easy/f_hard` are elements of `m`.

(1) If your transactions look roughly like this `m[f_easy(...)] = f_hard(...)`, use an `IORef` with `atomicModifyIORef`. Laziness will ensure that `m` is only locked for a short time as it's updated with a thunk. Calculating the index effectively locks the structure (as something is going to get updated, but we don't know what yet), but once it's known what that element is, the thunk over the entire structure moves to a thunk only over that particular element, and then only that particular element is "locked".

(2) If your transactions look roughly like this `m[f_hard(...)] = f_easy(...)`, and the don't conflict too much, use lots of `TVar`s. Using an `IORef` in this case will effectively make the app single threaded, as you can't calculate two indexes at the same time (as there will be an unresolved thunk over the entire structure). `TVar`s let you work out two indexes at the same time, however, the negative is that if two concurrent transactions both access the same element, and one of them is a write, one transaction must be scrapped, which wastes time (which could have been used elsewhere). If this happens a lot, you may be better with locks that come (via blackholing) from `IORef`, but if it doesn't happen very much, you'll get better parallelism with `TVar`s.

Basically in case (2), with `IORef` you may get 100% efficiency (no wasted work) but only use 1.1 threads, but with `TVar` if you have a low number of conflicts you might get 80% efficiency but use 10 threads, so you still end up 7 times faster even with the wasted work.

Comment: Is there a question here?  And I'm surprised `MVar` is entirely absent.

Comment: One other way to get "safe" variables then having multiple threads is to use channels  (http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html) and having a thread that supervises all the values and the other threads have to contact that one to get accces to a value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guidelines are somewhat similar to the findings of [1] (Section 6) where the performance of the Haskell STM is analyzed:

> "In particular, for programs that do not perform much work inside transactions, the commit overhead appears to be very high. To further observe this overhead, an analysis needs to be conducted on the performance of commit-time course-grain and fine-grain STM locking mechanisms."

I use `atomicModifyIORef` or an `MVar` when all the synchronization I need is something that simple locking will ensure. When looking at concurrent accesses to a data structure, it also depends on how this data structure is implemented. For example, if you store your data inside a `IORef Data.Map` and frequently perform read/write access then I think `atmoicModifyIORef` will degrade to a single thread performance, as you have conjectured, but the same will be true for a `TVar Data.Map`. My point is that it's important to use a data structure that is suitable for concurrent programming (balanced trees aren't).

That said, in my opinion the winning argument for using STM is *composability*: you can combine multiple operations into a single transactions without headaches. In general, this isn't possible using `IORef` or `MVar` without introducing new locks.

[1] The limits of software transactional memory (STM): dissecting Haskell STM applications on a many-core environment.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1366230.1366241

**Answer to @Clinton's comment:**

If a *single* `IORef` contains *all* your data, you can simply use `atomicModifyIORef` for composition. But if you need to process lots of parallel read/write requests to that data, the performance loss might become significant, since *every* pair of parallel read/write requests to that data might cause a conflict.

The approach that I would try is to use a data structure where the entries themselves are stored inside a `TVar` (vs putting the whole data structure into a single `TVar`). That should reduce the possibility of livelocks, as transactions won't conflict that often.

Of course, you still want to keep your transactions as small as possible and use composability only if it's absolutely necessary to guarantee consistency. So far I haven't encountered a scenario where combining more than a few insert/lookup operations into a single transaction was necessary.

Comment: Peter: I thought the problem with TVar is composability? You can always compose multiple operations using the `atomicModifyIORef` approach (if that IORef contains all your data).

Using `TVar`s though, if you have transaction TA1, TA2, ... that run every second and each time increment X, and transaction T2 that reads X, and then does work for 2 seconds before writing something, T2 never completes. You can't compose TA1, ... and T2 using `TVar`s. You could prevent livelock by giving transactions priority based on creation time, but `TVar` doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: @Clinton: I've added an answer to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond performance, I see a more fundamental reason to using `TVar`--the type system ensures you dont do any "unsafe" operations like `readIORef` or `writeIORef`.  That your data is shared is a property of the type, not of the implementation. EDIT: `unsafePerformIO` is always unsafe.  `readIORef` is only unsafe if you are also using `atomicModifyIORef`.  At the very least wrap your IORef in a newtype and only expose a wrapped `atomicModifyIORef`

Beyond that, don't use `IORef`, use `MVar` or `TVar`

1. The first usage pattern you describe probably does not have nice performance characteristics.  You likely end up being (almost) entirely single threaded--because of laziness no actual work happens each time you update the shared state, but whenever you need to use this shared state, the entire accumulated pile of thunks needs to be forced, and has a linear data dependency structure.
2. Having 80% efficiency but substantially higher parallelism allows you to exploit growing number of cores.  You can expect minimal performance improvements over the coming years on single threaded code.
3. Many word CAS is likely coming to a processor near you in the form of "Hardware Transactional Memory" allowing STMs to become far more efficient.
4. Your code will be more modular--every piece of code has to be changed if you add more shared state when your design has all shared state behind a single reference.  `TVars` and to a lesser extent `MVars` support natural modularity.

Comment: Regarding "unsafe" operations, there are always unsafe operations, e.g. "performUnsafeIO". It's just another unsafe operation we know to avoid unless we're really careful.

Comment: How do you use `MVar`? By continually calling `takeMVar` and `putMVar`? Isn't that similar to using an `IORef` and `atomicModifyIORef` anyway?

Comment: 1. You can easily fork off the work in parallel, there's no need to wait for these thunks to be forced. I believe `TVar`s are also lazy anyway, won't you get the same problem?

Comment: The fear I have with `TVar` is livelock. Namely that all transactions have to take less time to complete than your maximum gap between conflicts with that transaction. If there's a transaction T1 that runs every second that touches X, and another transaction T2 that reads X that takes 2 seconds to complete, T2 will never complete. The type system doesn't protect against this. Code can randomly fail depending on usage patterns. This is more difficult to avoid than simply not using "readIORef" and "writeIORef".

Comment: although in principle livelock is a problem, I'm not sure if anyone has any evidence of it actually causing the kinds of problems you describe with the current STM.  It is also possible for STM implementations to ensure some degree of fairness.

Comment: the potential advantage of MVar is that you can use more than 1, so long as you have a global order for access (to prevent deadlock).  Since `takeMVar` and `putMVar` are synchronized.

Comment: "You can easily fork off the work in parallel" my concern is this is not true.  All your updates depend on a single IORef, so have a global ordering which asserts a single linear data dependency path through all your data.  The parallelism is only local to a single operation, which you would be getting anyway from the spark pool.